# Regarding the usage of "being"

Tags: meaning

Does this sentence:

> When no data is being transmitted, D remains high

has the same meaning as

> When there is no data transmission, D remains high

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They might be interpreted the same way if the context is set appropriately, but the second, (When there is no data transmission) could also be referring to an error condition where transmission was expected but not achieved.) In other words, the first specifies the intent to transmit, the second only specifies the state but says nothing about intent. And it might be possible to be trying to send data with D pulled low, and have an error in another part of the system such that no data transfer occurs.